# Concatenating several subsets of one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes - one containing annotations with columns `label, timestamp, duration` and the other containing time series data with columns `timestamp, data_x, data_y, ...`

I want to pick out subsets of the time series dataframe based on conditions in the annotations. My time series dataframe is huge (~16M rows), and it is taking some time to perform the operation.

```py
import pandas as pd

annots = pd.read_csv('annotation_data.csv') # Columns [label, timestamp, duration]
data = pd.read_hdf('huge_data.h5')

subset_annots = annots[annots['label'] == 'some_condition')] 

# Iterating through rows of and picking out subsets as new dfs. 
dfs = [data[data['timestamp'].between(t[1],sum(t[1:]))] for t in subset_annots.itertuples(index=False, name=None)]

# Concatenate all subset dfs
subset_data = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

I am therefore wondering if there is a better way to do this, improving performance. Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT (see comment below):**

Example data

```
      participant_id  world_timestamp  world_index  gaze_timestamp    x_norm    y_norm     x_scaled     y_scaled  on_surf  confidence
0                  1         0.111063            0        0.069060  0.563072  0.971976  1081.097606  1166.371626     True         1.0
1000               1         4.167500           79        4.147512  0.616245  1.193779  1183.191197  1432.534741    False         1.0
2000               1         8.160631          170        8.183794  0.603852  1.081156  1159.395041  1297.386661    False         1.0
3000               1        12.227322          262       12.233595  0.488129  0.914511   937.208226  1097.412663     True         1.0
4000               1        16.262156          352       16.267485  0.730563  1.523592  1402.681123  1828.310433    False         1.0
```

Example annotations:

```
      participant_id    timestamp    duration  
1320               5    665.117126   60.001550  
1427               5    1681.441857  60.015723  
1552               6    187.458716   59.982354  
1662               6    1231.146065  60.005706  
1779               6    2266.880422  59.999420
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the dataset and annotations?

Comment: Two ideas, one is to create a mask using almost the same list comprehension you are using such as ```any([data.timestamp.between(i[1], i[1]+i[2]) for i in subset_annots.itertuples])```. So basically an ```or``` concat of the conditions and only filtering once by it. Or doing what you do, but in a highly parallized way using MultiProcessing

Comment: @mozway Not really important for this case I believe. Columns `timestamp, duration` in annotations marks start and end (sum of the two) for subsets in data, which is filtered out using `df.between(..)`. 

@FloLie Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: I disagree here, without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), one cannot try to reproduce what you did or to test an alternative method. If you don't want to share the underlying data, this is perfectly fine, but then provide at least a dummy example.

Comment: @mozway You're absolutely right! The data has a high sampling rate, but imagine rows continuing with different `participant_id` with timestamps continuing chronologically. A bit different than what was presented originally, but the row values in annotations is used to map out subsets in data.

Comment: If I understand well, for each row in the annotation dataframe, you calculate the beginning and end of an interval. Then you want to extract the values in your large dataframe where "world_timestamp" is within one of these intervals.
I eventually have an alternative solution, but the issue is that the provided example data give no output. Thus could you provide a better example (this is particularly important to test timing of the code)
Other question, is it fine if participant_id is different or should it match that of the annotations subset?

Comment: @mozway You are correct. `participant_id` is also used as a slicing condition, but this was not included in my minimal example. As there does not seem to be an obvious solution, I think I will leave it there. Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for not providing the necessary dummy data!